# Why Metal Shading Language is C++ but Metal itself isnt'?

Tags: c++, objective-c, shader, metal

I hope it's not too philosophical of a question to ask here and there's an actual pragmatic reasoning behind this engineering decision.

It seems like a subset of C++ is a very reasonable choice for a shading language, given that most game engines are written in C++ and the fact that there are many shading languages already with different potentially unfamiliar syntaxes which prompted the creation of custom shading languages and transpilers.

Why then, if Apple acklowleged these realities, they didn't provide a first class C++ Metal API?

Comment: The Metal API is supposed to be usable from many languages, and interoperating with C++ is tricky at best - very few languages can do it reasonably and pretty much none do it well. The shading language, being its own language with its own compiler, doesn't need to interoperate wih anything.

Comment: OK, fair. But they could've done what Cronos did with Vulkan by providing a C API and an official C++ wrapper.

Comment: @Vitaly That's both a Business and Technical decision and I doubt anyone outside of the people involved will be able to answer

Comment: Of course they could, but Apple has different financial incentives than Khronos. Also, the Vulkan C++ API is open source, and Apple usually doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

use the search functionality on the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/metal/sample-code/) webpages you will
 find the [Rendering a Scene with Deferred Lighting in C++](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/rendering_a_scene_with_deferred_lighting_in_c?language=objc) Example, which is mainly indeed written in C++.

The example is there since about 2018. It needs macOS 10.15 but also works on older machines that support metal with some tiny changes in code.

The Docs for this particular example are even written nicely with graphics to explain it in detail so you can follow up how it is done.

Because Apples webpages tend to support only Swift and Objective-C documentations it may help someone to find a direct link to the [RenderingASceneWithDeferredLightingInCPlusPlus.zip](https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/5b1a6d82d9/RenderingASceneWithDeferredLightingInCPlusPlus.zip).